# Different types of Astra (Weapons) which are mentioned in Mahabharata?

Tags: scripture, weapon

Can anyone tell me the different types of Astra(weapons) mentioned in the Mahabharata?
Thanks!!!

Comment: How is this too broad? I think it can be summarized.

Comment: @Yogi May be they think like that, So lets see what other think , If maximum person disagree then I don't have any problem if it will close.

Comment: I think Wikipedia has a list that is fairly long: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astra_(weapon)#Astras_in_Hindu_Epics

Comment: @Yogi This question is asking about mentioning all the Astra from Hindu scripture doesn't that make it too broad?

Comment: Though it is broad, I would love to see whole list at one place curated by a wiki post by our community. Anyway, try to make your post specific to one scripture like Mahabharata or Ramayana. I will vote to reopen then.

Comment: Sure, I edited it ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not able to tell all the astras used, but I shall tell  astras used by Arjuna only.

Deva Astra;
Nyana astra;
Asur Astra;
Shiva astra;
Sakthi Astra;
Parvata astra;
Gandharva Astra;
Manu astra;
Pashupat Astra;
Vaishnava astra;
Varuna Astra;
Narayana Astra;
Rudra Astra;
Bramha astra;
Bramashira Astra;
Bramhanda astra;
Agneyastra;
Indra Astra;
Naga Astra;
Naga Pasha;
Garuda Astra;
Mohini Astra;
Lord Shiv’s teen Baan;
Vasavi Shakti ;
Nalika Astra;
Varuna pasha;
Bhauma Astra;
Bhargava Astra;
Anjalika Astra ;
Vayva Astra;
Surya Astra;
Vajra;
Twashar Astra;
Sammohana/Pramohana Astra;
Maheshwara Astra;
Sabda deva Astra;
Linga Astra;
Vishnu Astra;
Yama Astra;
Krishna astra;
Maya Astra;
Rakshasa Astra;
Hari Astra ;
Hara Astra;
Sudharshana Astra;
Vinayaga Astra;
Tapasvee astra;
Yaksha Astra;
Harihara Astra;
Raghava astra;
Raghavendra Astra;
Sai Astra;
Maha Astra;
Karma astra;
Brihaspati Astra;
Matsya astra;
Kurma Astra ;
Varaha Astra;
Narasimha Astra;
Vamana Astra;
Parasurama Astra;
Rama Astra;
Buddha Astra;
Kalki Astra ;
Balarama Astra;
Kali Astra;
Saraswati Astra;
Lakshmi Astra;
Durga Astra;
Hanuman Astra;
Markandeya Astra;
Vyasa Astra;
Hayagreeva Astra;
Bhakti Astra;
Sindhi Astra;
Vega Astra;
Viveka Astra;
BhadhraKali Astra;
Durvasa Astra;
Veera Astra;
Vashishta Astra;
Uttama Astra;
Vishwamitra Astra;
Ashtalakshmi Astra; 
Dharieeya Lakshmi Astra;
Vera Lakshmi Astra;
Bhairava Astra;
Veerabhatra Astra;
Kartikeya Astra;
Muruga Astra;
Kritheka Astra;
Aadhi Astra;
Parasakthi Astra;
Aathma Astra;
Aadhiparasakthi Astra;
Dharma Astra;
Shyam Astra; 
Saharsa Astra;
Perusal Astra;
VishnuShiva Astra;
Pancha Astra;
Chandra Astra;

2 quiver of arrows – one with never ending arrows and the other with never – ending astras.

The Gandiva Bow which can never be broken and never misses its target.

Mace  of Lord Indra

Shiva Kaakam – The blade of lord shiv

Chandrahas – indestructible sword of lord shiv

Axe of Lord Varuna

Vishnu Kavach – a armour which protects from any weapon

The sword which was used by Lord Agni

A chakra which Lord Indra gave to Arjun

Nalika Arrows – Arrows of which will give extra power rather than a normal arrow.

A powerful noose

A scythe which Vishwakaram created for him.

A long weapon which shoots out the power of nature

A shield

The golden chariot which can fly upto the sky and can move by just thinking.(contains 4 white horses that move as fast as the wind.

Answer (score 4):

Following are the weapons mentioned in Mahabharata:

[Brahma weapon](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06048.htm)

[Aindra weapon](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06049.htm)

[Mahendra weapon](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06059.htm)

[Indra weapon](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06059.htm)

[Pramohana weapon](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06077.htm)

[Prajna weapon](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06077.htm)

[Varuna weapon](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06086.htm)

[solar weapon](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06102.htm)

[Vayavya weapon](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06103.htm)

[Saila weapon](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06103.htm)

[Parjanya weapon](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06123.htm)

[Soma weapon](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06123.htm)

[Parameshthi weapon](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06123.htm)

[Prajapati weapon](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06123.htm)

[Dhatri weapon](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06123.htm)

[Savitri weapon](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06123.htm)

[Tashtri weapon](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06123.htm)

[Saiva weapon](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07007.htm)

[Tvashtra weapon](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07019.htm)

[Vaishnava weapon](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07027.htm)

[Aditya weapon](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07028.htm)

[Agneya weapon](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07030.htm)

[Gandharva weapon](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07042.htm)

[Pasupata weapon](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07077.htm)

[Yamya weapon](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07153.htm)

[Anjalika weapon](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07172.htm)

[Asani of Rudra's](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07172.htm)

[Sthunakarna weapon](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07178.htm)

[Narayana weapon](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07191.htm)

[Naga weapon](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m08/m08053.htm)

[Sauparna weapon](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m08/m08053.htm)

[Bhargava weapon](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m08/m08064.htm)

[Brahmashira weapon](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m10/m10012.htm)

[Discus of Krishna](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m10/m10012.htm)

[Trident of Siva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03230.htm)

Also some other weapons are mentioned as:

Mace

Sword

Spear

This list is not inexhaustible. So, it will be updated in time.

Comment: You forgot the Brahmanda Astra.